# Comparing unevenly spaced time series

Tags: r, time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have multiple sets of time series data. However, the spacing of observation times is not constant within a time series itself, nor is it consistent between different time series.

For example, series A might have observations at `0900, 0930, 1100, 1200, 1330`. Series B might have observations at `0800, 0815, 0830, 0925, 1300, etc`.

I'm trying to use this data to look for crossovers between series based on their time and the value at that time. For example, given

```
Series A = [(0900, 25), (0930, 31), (1100, 22), (1200, 25)]
Series B = [(0815, 23), (0830, 27), (0925, 31)]
```

We could say that there's a crossover at `A: (0930, 31)` and `B: (0925, 31)` - their times are relatively close and their values are the same.

I understand how to compare series that have a common frequency of measurement, but I'm completely stumped as to how to deal with unevenly spaced series. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't quite see what "crossover" means in this context. It is true that your 2 examples have the same values at relatively similar times, but what is the point of that? What is it you are ultimately trying to do here?

Comment: In this context, I just mean whether there are two values that are equal at relatively similar times. This is actually a simplification of the original problem. The proper dataset is time series location data. I.e. at some time _t_, a person is at location _(x, y)_. My goal is to determine whether two people are at the same location at relatively similar times. However, I'm more focused on the problem of the unevenly spaced series.

Comment: What constitutes "relatively similar times"?

Comment: It's variable - something that I'd like to be able to fine tune. But lets say, for example, I consider two people to 'meet' if they're at the same (x, y) coords at a timestamp with a difference of <= 5 minutes